# VirtualBox Extension Pack for 14.04.1 LTS (Virtualbox 4.3.10)

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, extension

Where might I find the Virtualbox Extension pack for 14.04.1 LTS (64bit)

I installed virtualbox via synaptic. The version it installed is 4.3.10
I can't seem to locate a corresponding Extension pack.

My fallback would be to install directly but I'm curious to see if it's available.

Comment: sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ext-pack should be more easy to install it

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I found it after a bit more digging...

http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.10/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.10-93012.vbox-extpack

Comment: To install, just double click on it and virtualbox will ask you if you want to add the extension pack. (source: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#intro-installing)

Comment: In Ubuntu,  virtualbox version 4.3.10, not finding any option called extension. Also nothing is happening when the the above extpack file is opened using virtualbox. Can anyone help?

Comment: Open main options, select plugins, select .vbox-extpack and it will install it

Answer (score 8):

For version 5 the link is: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.2/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.0.2-102096.vbox-extpack

This worked for me ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, version 5 has not been included in the Software Center Repos yet and has to be installed through a deb file, which, I think is not what the OP is not asking.